# Capture mysql database error and use it in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I created the following table for user to user subscriptions.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subscriptions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscribed_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_subscription` (`user_id`,`subscribed_to`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=76 ;
```

I'm disallowing identical rows by making the columns `user_id` and `subscribed_to` unique. If a user tries to resubmit the same data I get:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1062
>
> Duplicate entry '62-88' for key 'unique_subscription'
>
> INSERT INTO subscriptions (user_id, subscribed_to, date) VALUES ('62',
>   '88', '2011-07-11 19:15:13')
>
> Line Number: 330

I'm preventing the database error by checking if an identical row exists before trying to insert data.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscriptions WHERE (user_id = '62' AND subscribed_to = '88')";

if ($query > 0)
{
    //display already subscribed message
}
else
{
    //insert new row
}
```

The database already checks the table and returns an error. The `select count(*)` query above seems redundant. Do I really need to check the table once more in my application? Is there a way to capture the database error if it occurs, and do something with that in my application?

If you have an idea how please share an example. I haven't a clue how this is done..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out PHP function [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

You can wrap the db call within a `try catch` statement for functions that throw exceptions to prevent your application from crashing.

PHP function `mysql_query` does not throw exception on error, but returns `FALSE`. You can check the return value and execute `mysql_error` to find out the trouble or log it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please provide an example? I'm not sure how this is done

Comment: which PHP function are you using to run the queries? is it `mysql_query`?

Comment: I'm using activerecord via the codeigniter framework which I believe uses mysql_query

Comment: `$this->db->_error_message();` will give you the error message using codeigniter. Check out [this forum thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/76524/#384387) for more.